# SQL question need to add the values in one column and remove duplicates after adding the columns in another column

Tags: sql

I want to add the column values based on the remove duplicates in another column

Need the data like as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's called an "aggregation". You can do it like:

```
select
  name,
  max(date) as date, -- MAX() gets the max value from the group
  sum(expense) as expense -- SUM() adds up all the values of the group
from t
group by name
```